# read multi record layer text file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a txt file which has the data in the below format.

```html
#FILE_HEADER# MOnth|1901124578965
#MEMBERSHIP_PERSON# 9999944999|0009999|05|ABC|F|Medium|REGN|||07/Jun/2017|Pay Pal|||N|DISTIBUTOR|CURRENT|01|Y|Annual|2017|EXISTING|01/Jan/1901
#ADDRESS_LINE# 0059999999|Mr|Test||Test||M|03/Jan/1901|009999900|Online|abc00@abc.com.au|N|N|00244444||11 ABC Street|||SUBURB|3003|SA|Australia|N|N|00999900|Email|abc00@abc.com.au|N|N|||||||Y|Y|0000000001|YZx|0000000001|ZYX|PERSON|N|0000000000||||||0000000000|||||
#PAYMENT_LINE# 1234|123|35|First Last
#PAYMENT_LINE# 123|123|12|First Last
#MLS# 123|123
#SOC_YHC# 00099999|First||Last|01|03/Jan/1901|01/Jan/1901|30|00000|01/Jul/1901|00|C|01/Jul/1901|Y|
#SOC_YHC# 00099999|First|F|Last|02|03/Jan/1901|01/Jan/1901|30|00000|01/Jul/1901|00|C|01/Jul/1901|Y|
#SOC_MEMBERSHIP# Mr|First||Last|12 ABC Street|SUBURB  SA  3003|||3003|C|Couples|996|PRODUCT||01/O1/1901|30.256%|225|211|145
#SIS# N
#FILE_FOOTER# 1901eExtractionOptIn_0000.txt|12345|1901124578965
```

The headers are not in the file.The file layout is below:
The data provided above is in between the file header and file footer, and every row of data starts with #MEMBERSHIP_PERSON.
The end goal is to convert this data into a table (columns as below and row data as above)

```html
#FILE_HEADER# <TAXGENERATIONMODE>|<BATCHPROCESSSTARTDATETIME>
#MEMBERSHIP_PERSON# <STATEMENT ID>|<MEMBERSHIP NUMBER>|<FUND NO>|<HEALTH FUND ID>|<MEMBERSHIP STATUS>|<STATEMENT COMPLEXITY>|<MEMBERSHIP REBATE STATUS>|<REBATE TIER EFFECTIVE DATE>|<REBATE TIER>|<DATE PAID TO>|<PAYMENT METHOD>|<ORGX TYPE>|<ORGX GROUP DPT>|<REBATE TYPE>|<PERSON CATEGORY>|<PERSON STATUS>|<PERSON SUFFIX NUMBER>|<MULTIPLE ADULTS>|<STATEMENT_TYPE>|<STATEMENT _YEAR>|<STATEMEMT_FREQ>|<STATEMENT GENERATE DATE>
#ADDRESS_LINE# <PERSON TITLE>|<PERSON GIVEN NAME>|<PERSON INITIAL>|<PERSON SURNAME>|<PERSON PREFERRED NAME>|<PERSON GENDER>|<PERSON DOB>|<MAILING CONTACT ID>|<MAILING CONTACT TYPE>|<MAILING CONTACT>|<ADDRESS ID>|<ADDRESSEE>|<ADDRESS LINE 1>|<ADDRESS LINE 2>|<ADDRESS LINE 3>|<CITY/TOWN>|<POSTCODE>|<STATE/PROVINCE/REGION>|<COUNTRY>|<ADDRESS UNKNOWN>|<ADDRESS INVALID>|<ONLINE NOTIFICATION CONTACT ID>|<ONLINE NOTIFICATION CONTACT TYPE>|<ONLINE NOTIFICATION CONTACT>|<ONLINE NOTIFICATION CONTACT UNKNOWN>|<ONLINE NOTIFICATION CONTACT INVALID>|<COURTESY NOTIFICATION CONTACT ID>|<COURTESY NOTIFICATION TYPE>|<COURTESY NOTIFICATION CONTACT>|<COURTESY NOTIFICATION CONTACT UNKNOWN>|<COURTESY NOTIFICATION CONTACT INVALID>|<COMBINED AUTHORITY>|<COMPANY REGISTRATION>|<COMMS CATEGORY>|<COMMS CATEGORY ENTITY>|<MEMBERSHIP STATUS>|<PERSON STATUS>
#PAYMENT_LINE# <PREMIUMS PAID>|<REBATE RECEIVED>|<REBATE CODE>|<OTHER BENEFICIARY>
#MLS# <TOTAL HOSPITAL DAYS>|<TOTAL HOLIDAY DAYS>
#SOC_LHC# <MEMBERSHIP NUMBER>|<GIVEN>|<INITIAL>|<SURNAME>|<SUFFIX>|<DOB>|<START-DATE>|<CERT-ENT-AGE>|<TOT-ABSENT-DAYS>|<ABSENT-DAYS-AS-AT>|<LIFE-LOADING>|<CONFIRM-IND>|<ISSUE-DATE>|<PROJ-AB-DAYS>|<BABYCARE EXCESS WAIVER FLAG>
#SOC_MEMBERSHIP# <TITLE>|<GIVEN>|<INITIAL>|<SURNAME>|<ADDRESS LINE 1>|<ADDRESS LINE 2>|<ADDRESS LINE 3>|<ADDRESS LINE 4>|<POSTCODE>|<MEMB-CODE>|<MEMB-TYPE LMEMTP>|<PACKAGE-CODE>|<PACKAGE-DESC>|<HOSP-CORE-CODE LHSPCC>|<COVER-DATE-FROM>|<CURR-REBATE>|<HOSP-OPT-ID>|<ANC-OPT-ID>|<NP-OPT-ID>
#SIS# <HAS SIS FLAG> 
#FILE_FOOTER# <FILENAME>|<TOTALRECORDSCOUNT>|<BATCHPROCESSFINISHDATETIME>
```

**Question**

How do I read this file?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  We won't write the code for you, unfortunately, but we can help debug existing code.

Comment: Ask your question in the body of your question, not in the subject line.